# Why didn't the bartender allow Robbie Hart to drink at the bar?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-wedding-singer

In The Wedding Singer, why didn't the Bartender allow Robbie to drink at the bar?

> Robbie Hart: I brought my own.
>
> Bartender: You can't drink that in here.

Comment: Normally, bars don't allow to drink what you brought.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because most public houses are bound by law to ensure only alcohol purchased on the premises is consumed on the premises.

Infact, many states operate with different types of licenses; 'on' licenses (such as the one mentioned here), and 'off' licenses (common in the UK) where alcohol must be taken off the premises before it can be drunk.

Not only does this aid in regulation, it also ensures the bar is able to control and 'cut off' it's patrons if they have imbibed too much alcohol, which is both a legal and a moral responsibility of any licensee.